# How to Disable Keyboard Settings Button on Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I was wondering if it's possible to prevent the user from being able to press on the settings button on the keyboard and changing the theme of it on Android Studio? Apparently you can add any picture you want to it and I would like to know if theres a way to disable that.

From the screenshot below, you can see there is a settings icon on the right of the clipboard, which opens the next screenshot I attached -> when the user presses Theme, they can change the background image to any picture.

[image: Keyboard]

[image: Keyboard Settings]

Comment: That is a feature of GBoard, which is one keyboard among hundreds. Those internal features will vary by keyboard, and apps generally cannot control them.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. If you have very high permissions you can block every keyboard app and make the user only available to use an  alternative keyboard app you made which doesn't have this option. but why do you need this?

Comment: @ATP my job ... they have Android devices that our employees use and they are able to customize and put inappropriate pictures on the Work device keyboard, and they want to disable this.

Comment: Keyboards are basically apps, and one app can't control what another app allows the user to do. If you want to prevent this kind of thing, you'd either need to look at locking the work devices down as managed devices, or just implement a workplace policy saying what's acceptable and what isn't on work devices

Comment: They can put the pictures as wallpaper too... you can't have a full control on the device. My suggest to you is to set a passcode to the device and enable screen pinning on the device settings: https://support.google.com/android/answer/9455138?hl=en   ,  pin the app and now every time someone will try to exit the application he will have to type the pin to exit the app (to unpin the screen). otherwise he won't be able to switch apps. (including changing keyboard settings if remember right)

Comment: @ATP huh great suggestion, I'll look into that!

Comment: @AndroidDev just curios... did it work?

Comment: @ATP Our company uses Zebra EMDK so I was able to do it through there

Answer (score 0):

This could help a bit….
Click on Gear icon within GBoard
Go to Text Correction
Disable “Show Suggestion strip”

Comment: Your answer seems better suited as a comment rather than an actual answer. Please consider adding it as a comment to the relevant post.